# fastest way to search static facts with swi prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Is there a faster way to compile or index a large number of facts to improve speed? I have roughly 30K facts of the form linked(groupid,id)

and try to find connections given an id, but it is really slow.  I use the rules

```
connected(Id1,Id2) :-
   linked(Grp1,Id1),
   linked(Grp1,Id2),
   \+Id1=Id2.

connected(Id1,Id2) :-
   connected(Id1,Id3),
   connected(Id3,Id2),
   \+Id1=Id2,!.
```

Comment: See: https://lists.iai.uni-bonn.de/pipermail/swi-prolog/2011/007061.html

Answer (score 3):

Most Prologs use indexing on the first argument of the predicate, so reordering the arguments sometimes might be a good idea. In some Prolog dialects, such as SWI, you can explicitly indicate how the indexing should be done using the :-index directive.

Your implementation suggests a transitive closure variant. If Id1 and Id2 are ground you can consider distinguishing the recursive and the non-recursive case (1) and replacing the first call to connected/2 in the body of the second clause by a call to the non-recursive case (2). Finally, you can consider keeping track of the visited Ids such that you will not need to revisit them.

Comment: SWI, YAP, Jekejeke index on several arguments, so you do no longer need `:- index` directives.

Answer (score 0):

For extrême situations maybe you have to use C/C++ to recode thé linked facts and thé connecte prédicate. Further optimisation; return full liste of connected objects.